# Al Hannisim for Yom Ha'atzmaut and Yom Yerushalayim

Tags: minhag, shemoneh-esrei, yom-haatzmaut, yom-yerushalayim

Are there any special additions one can add to the shemoneh esrei on Yom Ha'atzmaut and Yom Yerushalayim?
Is there any problem with saying these additions? Do any major shuls in America say them?

Comment: I would think that if Ezra HaSofer (a Navi and the founder of Anshei Kineses Hagedolah) did not make any additions or changes regarding *tefilah* even for the day he started or finished building the second Bais HaMikdash then it is a bit premature for us to do so for just being let back into some of our rightful territory and for being allowed to self-govern.

Comment: @Yahu yet Ezra and his generation had only endured 70 years without a Beis Hamikdash. Now, after almost 2000 years, perhaps every little victory is more worthy of extra excitement?

Comment: @Yahu Seems like a judgment call for a posek. And there are those who've paskened in every possible direction. I think that the best answers to this question would quote from the contemporary posekim or describe practices in communities that are under their direction.

Comment: @Jeremy, the operative word is "Perhaps".

Comment: @Yahu Who says Ezra didn't make changes?  The current Shemonah Esrei was only written after the destruction of the second temple! This is obvious as 3 of the brachot, ask for the return of the beit hamikdash

Comment: @Yahu They did make changes and we still celebrate that holiday on 25 Kislev, the day they started building the Second Temple (See Chaggai 2).

Comment: @Avi you are correct but you did not read my comment carefully: He did not make any changes for the day he started or finished building the second temple. I was just pointing out that there is an a fortiori here: He didn't for actual rebuilding the temple, so why should we for merely (relatively speaking!) getting independence and winning back Yerushalayim?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Chaggai 2 does tell us the date. What we celebrate happened many years later, and yes they made some additions to Teffila based on it. Where is your source that Ezra made changes to the Tefillah upon building the new Temple? I have heard that there are sources that some felt that Hallel should be said and others did not but I have not seen them. The essence of my point is that getting back a bit of Eretz Yisrael and getting back Yerushalayim are great smiles from Heaven, but until we have a Bais Hamikdash there is no definitive source for change.

Comment: and @avi, yes Rabbi Yochanan ben Zakkai made certain significant changes to the liturgy to reflect the destruction of the Temple (the essence of the loss of Yerushalayim). This just underscores my point: when we have a bais hamikdash we will have a definitive precedent for making changes.

Comment: @Yahu There is "circumstantial" evidence that 25 Kislev was important before Chanukah as well. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22721/759 I agree I can't rigorously prove it.

Comment: @DoubleAA That it was important is clear from Chagai 2, as you mentioned. That changes were made to Tefilla . . .?

Comment: @Jeremy, extra excitement, of course! But we are talking about a halakhic matter. The safest measure would be that the last time insertions were made was the Gaonim for Aseres Yemei Teshiva and before that, changes were made by Rabi Yochanan Ben Zakkai, corresponding to the loss of the Bais Hamikdash. The Gaonic changes were not made out of excitement or its opposite; rather due to Yeridat HoDorot and a growing recognition that this Golus was for the long haul (same with their addition of HaRahamans to Bircas HaMazone). The changes and insertions that Rabi Yochanan Ben Zakkai made were . . .

Comment: about Aveilus for loss of the Bais Hamikdash. That being the case, let's get our Bais Hamikdash and then we will have a definitive source for us to make changes to the status quo Tefillah.

Comment: @Yahu Seems pretty reasonable that they celebrated it liturgically as well somehow. I don't know how as I don't really know what their liturgy looked like frankly.

Comment: It was probably a lot shorter than ours but with the same essential berachos. See http://www.hakirah.org/Vol14Zelcer.pdf and  also see http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%2012%20FrimerA.pdf for one critique of one analysis regarding changes in the liturgy in general nowadays.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://machonshilo.org/en/images/stories/files/183_Machon_Shilo_Al_HaNissim_YA_YY_Revised.pdf) are two possible texts according to Nusach Eretz Yisrael (machon shilo).

I had also seen a longer text used in the [Great Synagoge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Synagogue_of_Rome) in Rome, but don't have an electronic text.

I would think that one could add them in either Shema Koleinu or Modim (maybe even Bonei Yerushalayim?) without concern, as long as the standard chatima is used.

Comment: if *bonei yerushalayim*, then why not also *t'ka b'shofar gadol*?

Comment: You can add prayers to shma koleinu, but not necessarily modim. Even though the original al hanisim is in modim, its not so simple to add to the 1st 3 or last 3 brachos.

Comment: @ArielK - I understand not adding to the first three, but why not the last three?

Comment: Worth noting that those texts aren't according to Nusach Eretz Yisrael. There is no Nusach EY on the matter (for obvious reasons). They are just texts promulgated by the same people who advocate for praying Nusach EY.