# Why don't we celebrate Cyrus' edict to grant freedom to the Jews and to erect the Second Temple?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, purim

In my understanding of history, Cyrus the Great was the person who saved Judaism from vanishing not only by granting them the freedom of worship and letting them return to the Promised Land but by heavily funding the rebuilding of the Temple.

In fact, IIRC, he's the only one called God's Messiah ([Isaiah.45.1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.45.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en), "*Thus said the LORD to Cyrus, His anointed one*"). And this story is far more historically significant and real than Purim's.

Why don't we celebrate [Cyrus' edict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edict_of_Cyrus) and the re-establishment of the Second Temple?

Comment: David in Sam 2:23:1. Shaul in Sam 1:26:11. Among other places.

Comment: This feels like something that would have been in megillat taanit. I don't know why it wasn't, but the same sort of reason we don't follow that anymore would seem to apply here.

Comment: What specific date would be used? The day it was announced? The day someone received the letter? Who?

Comment: @DoubleAA Usually we pick dates first and tie events later. Any date would be good, but how about the date of the declaration, the day Ezrah entered Jerusalem, the day the first brick was laid?

Comment: @AlBerko what is the relevance/significance of "anointed one" towards your question?

Comment: @AlBerko we do celebrate the day of the first brick laying https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22721/759

Answer (score 2):

Rashi on Ezra 1:1 says : "When Israel returned from the Babylonian exile to the land of Israel, in that year, in the first year of Cyrus, Israel laid the foundation of the Temple, and the adversaries of Judah and Benjamin slandered them to Cyrus, the king of Persia, and he commanded [them] to curtail the work, no longer to build the edifice of the Temple; and the Israelites were idle, for they did not build the Temple during the entire reign of Cyrus and Ahasuerus, who succeeded him, until the second year of Darius [the Great]..."

Ibn Ezra says the same on 1:4.

Comment: Please expound on your argument, I can't decipher the quote alone.

Comment: My point is that Cyrus' edict only ended up indirectly leading to the building of the second temple much later according to Rashi. The construction of the temple only began 18 years later. The question of why we don't celebrate the building of the second temple is still valid, but the connection to the edict is not necessarily as strong as it might seem.

Comment: Per your comment, so it seems that this answer is more of a comment on the question than an answer.

Comment: I would consider it a partial answer, the question being "Why don't we celebrate Cyrus' edict and the re-establishment of the Second Temple?" This addresses the first part.